# Grails: POST or GET httprequest params only

Tags: spring, grails

In controller and gsp there are avaliable two variables:

- `params` - tahat contains map of all params (both GET from Query String and POST from forms)
- `request` - the `HttpServletRequest` object

How can I get POST only params or GET (query string) only params? I need both types of params but in different maps.

I know, that `HttpServletRequest` object contains information about Query String, but I'm looking for solution without implementing parser of query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by parsing Query String with `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils` and then I put these data into `HttpServletRequest` attribute.

Now I can use `request.getAttribute('paramsGet')` or `request.getAttribute('paramsPost')`.

The Grails filters was very helpfull, so:

```
package com.selly.filters

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils

class ParamsFilters {

    List globalParams = [
        "controller",
        "action",
        "format"
    ]

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {
                Map paramsRequest = params.findAll {
                    return !globalParams.contains(it.key)
                }

                Map paramsGet = WebUtils.fromQueryString(request.getQueryString() ?: "")
                Map paramsPost = paramsRequest.minus(paramsGet)

                request.setAttribute('paramsGet', paramsGet)
                request.setAttribute('paramsPost', paramsPost)

                //println request.getAttribute('paramsGet')
                //println request.getAttribute('paramsPost')
            }
            after = { Map model ->

            }
            afterView = { Exception e ->

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even with Grails, you're working with Servlet which mix up POST and GET. And I don't remember seeing something (except for reparsing the Query String) which would help you.

Comment: I have managed to solve this problem. Unfortunately with parsing query string.